# Report and Chart problem

Tags: reporting, dashboard, charts, analytics, history-tracking

I have a problem that i couldn't solve for 2 days.I need to do something like this to see the daily difference.

http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-4EoAZUOPawE/UTCHnW-tzFI/AAAAAAAAAG8/IUja9w7S0qc/s1600/EVGraph.jpg
(excel made)
[image: Chart trying to be made]

I tried to create this chart in report.I created summary report and took all the fields that i need and saved it.Then i created a dashboard and used this report but it didn't let me because of not to have grouping on it.I checked the fields if i could use any of them for grouping but there is no suitable field for it.Then i used project history with using track field history.After some trying process i did it with plot chart but it is just for the day when it's edited.I edited  the cost values in Project object and customized the  EV-AV-PV(Earned Value etc.) report and obtained the second plot chart with new edit date.But, although I have the correct old and new values in report,the summarized values(without summarizing i just had record count for grouping) of a day ago(other edit date) also changed  when i edited the values of project.Then  I created an object with analytic snapshot.After i got the values with analytic snapshot i made a report with this values but i couldn't have a logical chart because all the values which came from analytic snapshot are Links and different for every project and directs me to the custom object that i created for analytic snapshot.I found a different thing which called Historical Trend.I made a Historical trend for analytic snapshot values object and the values in Project object.I made two reports with their own historical trending types, made the adjustments and run it but it didn't give the results of yesterday like how it showed in the picture in Url below.Today and yesterday are same.Is there anybody here who has any idea about how to solve that?Thank you.

http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-gb/winter14/release-notes/rn_186_analytics_trending.htm

Comment: user8133 - you'll get  more help if you reword your question to not be a giant run-on paragraph that is hard to parse. Try to frame the question to your 'best attempt so far' and identify specific aspects of that 'best attempt' that will enable others to assist